# Input title goes away

Tags: css, html, input

I have an input for text with a placeholder. As soon as you click the input the placeholder moves up and stays as a title. The problem is that when I start typing that title goes away.

```css
.material-input-login {
  margin: 8px 10px;
  width: 200px;
  /* display: block; */
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 96%, #fff 4%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 96%, #fff 4%);
  background-position: -200px 0;
  background-size: 200px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #fff;
}
.material-input-login:focus, .material-input-login:valid {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.material-input-login:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder, .material-input-login:valid::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  visibility: visible !important;
}
.material-input-login::-webkit-input-placeholder, .material-button {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<input id="searchBox" type="search" placeholder="Search" class="material-input-login" required="">
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on frontend but that's what a placeholder is supposed to do. Maybe you can solve it playing with the value attr. In any case the effect create is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that placeholders disappear when you begin typing - I'm not aware of any CSS tricks that will allow you to avoid this behaviour.

I've had a go at making an alternative that uses the input label instead:

https://jsfiddle.net/zug5j8m5/

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #333;
}

.material-input-login {
  margin: 0 10px 8px;
  width: 200px;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 96%, #fff 4%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 96%, #fff 4%);
  background-position: -200px 0;
  background-size: 200px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #fff;
}

.material-input-login:focus, .material-input-login:valid {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.label {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-35px);
          transform: translateY(-35px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.material-input-login:focus+.label {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px);
          transform: translateY(-50px);
  display:block !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="searchBox" type="search" title="Search" class="material-input-login" required="">
<label for="searchBox" class="label">Search</label>
```

Comment: It works but it has a problem. If you type and then unclick the box it comes back down and it should stay up because there is text in the input

Answer (score -1):

Here is what makes it moves up:

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
      transform: translateY(-20px);
```

translateY allows you to move the placeholder -20px above. Just remove it or change the number if you want.